Responsive Design from a slider element
I have started coding a small website that has a map on the right hand side which incorporates a slider for resizing of the map, I have tried using @media for resizing and this works when using chrome inspect to reduce the screensize, however when i resize the component with the map slider nothing happens ??
What would be the best way to achieve this

How do I ask a good question?, minimal reproducible example
